# Pass chart title as parameter to drill through report

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

Does anyone know if there is a way to pass the title of a chart/graph to a drill-through report?  When you setup the drill-through definitions, there does not appear to be an option to select.  Only the pass data value and pass parameter options are available.

I also tried to select the string in the query so it would be available as a data item value but since it is not used in the calculation of the graph, it does not pass the value.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a data item in the query for the chart with a static text string which equals the chart title. This would not be used in the generation of the graph on the parent report. On the drill target report, make sure to create a parameter for this graph title. It won't be able to be in the filters section of the query, so you'll likely need to make it a prompt macro within a data item of the query itself. Then you should just be able to link these fields in the drill through definition by passing the data item value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click one of the chart axes,
2. Find data: Properties property
3. Click the ellipsis
4. Select the data item which you wanted to pass.

Comment: I am able to select the data element but it seems to change the results of the graph.